# Adding Decimal Places

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'col1': [999, 1000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How would I loop through this data frame and add a decimal two places from the right for values higher than 200. For example, 999 is greater than 200 so make that 9.99

Comment: So would `999` become `9.99`?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Just edited the last part sorry, it would iterate through and add those decimals throughout the entire data frame only if greater than a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

> **If you want apply in all columns [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):**

```
df = df.mask(df.ge(200),df.div(100))
```

If you want apply in one Serie Use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['col1']= df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].ge(200),df['col1'].div(100))
```

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)
d = {'col1': np.random.randint(0,1000,10),
    'col2': np.random.randint(0,500,10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

   col1  col2
0   520   354
1   792    53
2   835    66
3   871   226
4   855    14
5    79   290
6   944   497
7   906   240
8   350   280
9   948   143
df = df.mask(df.ge(200),df)
print(df)
   col1  col2
0   520   354
1   792    53
2   835    66
3   871   226
4   855    14
5    79   290
6   944   497
7   906   240
8   350   280
9   948   143
```

Another options [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
 df=df.where(df.lt(200),df.div(100))
#df['col1']=df['col1'].where(df['col1'].lt(200),df['col1'].div(100))
```

or [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.ge(200),df.div(100),df),
                  columns = df.columns,index = df.index)
```

**Output for your sample df**

```
    col1
0   9.99
1  10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `applymap()` with a conditional `lambda` function that will divide by 100 if the cell value is greater than 200.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [999, 1000, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x/100 if x >= 200 else x) 
print(df)
```

output:

```
     col1
0    9.99
1   10.00
2  100.00
```

Comment: why apply map here?

Comment: @ansev because if he adds more columns to this, your above functions won't work. ```applymap()``` applies over every element of a data frame.

Comment: also, ```np.where``` is calling in a native ```numpy``` function on a pandas data frame so you're doing a type conversion back to ```np.matrix``` to be able to use it. you should use native pandas functions when able.

Comment: for more columns is the same

Comment: @ansev no you would need to specify the columns as you did above. that's verbose why not just use applymap to do it to every column.

Comment: @ansev you're naming the columns here: ```df['col1']...```

Comment: with np.where we can also... `df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.ge(200),df.div(100),df),columns = df.columns,index = df.index)`

Comment: the problem with `applymap` is that it can become slow in large data frames

Comment: @ansev its not slow- its a vectorized function. pandas is built using dplyr R framework which is way faster.

Comment: @ansev and again, you're using numpy functions on something that's a pandas data frame so you're adding in a type conversion. If this data frame is large your suggested methods would not only be time consuming to type out EVERY column name to apply those over- but then you have to type convert the data frame and convert back.

Comment: please check..`import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)
d = np.random.randint(0,1000,(10000,5000))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)` with `%%timeit`

Comment: `%%timeit
df.applymap(lambda x: x/100 if x >= 200 else x) 
21.3 s ± 510 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: `%%timeit
df.mask(df.ge(200),df.div(100))
10.1 s ± 302 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: `%timeit
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.ge(200),df.div(100),df),columns = df.columns,index = df.index)
5.78 s ± 388 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`